# Change keras class_weight during training

Tags: callback, keras

I want to make use of the **class_weight** parameter of the fit function in Keras to deal with unbalanced datasets.

The key inhere is that i want to specify the **class_weights** through a function based on the epoch that is running.

I though to use a callback function but I'm unable to change the **class_weight** parameter from there. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment it is unfortunately not possible to change the `class_weight` parameter in a callback function. The parameter is not saved as an instance variable in the model, so you won't be able to access it.

You can however adjust the class weight parameter for each batch, if you use `model.train_on_batch`. You will be able to calculate the epoch number from the batch number. This only works for this particular fit method, though. So you will need to create a batch generator and modify the class weight parameter before passing on the batch of data to the fit function.

Comment: Thanks @maikovich for the answer :).